# Duplicate Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, web, hosting

I am writing to see if anyone has any tips on how one might be able to duplicate a Wordpress site.

We have branded and designed a research study site, and would like to copy this site entirely and rebrand it for a different study.

Does anyone know what might need to go into this to do so? Having trouble figuring this out!

Best,
Taylor

Comment: yess you can use wordpress plugins for that purpose

Comment: Maybe research over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question really has nothing to do with programming and is off-topic for this community.  There are lots of guides available (with multiple solutions) for copying Wordpress sites, which can be easily found with a Google search.  I'd suggest starting there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "rebrand". To just duplicate the site should be a relatively easy job to do. You will have to download everything from you `public_html` and also get a backup of your database. Then upload the files from public_html to a new hosting and also import the database.

After that part now arise some more things. First of the domain name. You will need to change the domain name to reflect a new one you want to use -- i will not get into details about that since you can find lots of good tutorials on how to do that with simple googling. If you need to change any pictures/logos and anything else since you designed it you should know what to change.

Then if there are remaining parts that need to be changed, for example there are many cases in texts fields where the brand of the previous research site is mentioned then I can suggest using a tool like [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) which is the only tool currently that comes to my mind for such a cache. It is a really useful and powerful tool but it requires you to have access to ssh to the hosting.
If i come up with something else as well, I will update this.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've all been very helpful! If I have trouble going forward I'll be sure to head over to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/